# multiple line autoresizing text UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

Is it possible to have a multiline UILabel that auto-resizes the UIFont size so that it fits into the frame size of a UILabel? If not then what is the best way to achieve this? I don't want to adjust the frame size of the UILabel/UITextView to whatever. So far I've been doing it like this:

```
int currentFontSize = 18;
    UIFont *currentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNovaBold size:currentFontSize];
    CGSize storyTitleSize = [storyTitle sizeWithFont:currentFont constrainedToSize:self.newsfeedStoryTitle_.frameSize];

    while (storyTitleSize.height >= self.newsfeedStoryTitle_.frameHeight){
        currentFontSize--;
        currentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNovaBold size:currentFontSize];
        storyTitleSize = [storyTitle sizeWithFont:currentFont constrainedToSize:self.newsfeedStoryTitle_.frameSize];
    }

    [self.newsfeedStoryTitle_ setFont:currentFont];
    [self.newsfeedStoryTitle_ setText:storyTitle];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want: `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` [[Source]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3alineBreakMode%3a)

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, NSIntegerMax);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [theString sizeWithFont:the Font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:theLineBreakMode];   

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = theLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
theLabel.frame = newFrame;
```